# OpenGL How to draw curves being part of circle depends of last point location with requirements: fixed radius, last point givig direction

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, trigonometry

I can not put questions in one line also here they are:

How to draw a curve which is part of the circle(depending on the end point)

Let:

- p1=(x1,y1) be the first point
- have to be line p2=(x2,y2) is the starting point of drawing the curve
- p3=(x3,y3) be the end point (mouse location)

Requirements:

- if P3 is going closer to p2, the larger the potential radius becomes
- p3 describes the drawing direction
- if p3 is pararel to p2 there nothing should be drawn (or drawn line p3>p2)
- if p3 is equal to p1 it should draw a relatively large wheel,

**EDIT:**
I think i found solution how to draw that part of circle, please look at that gifs below:

[image]

Comment: The radiuses in the animation look far from fixed.  Perhaps you can describe how that is supposed to work better

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088902/what-is-the-radius-of-a-circle-given-two-points-and-the-center-of-the-circle-is

Comment: Please correct your requirements. What does "if p3 is pararel to p2" mean? It makes no sense as both p3 and p2 are points.

Comment: @Brieg.  It looks as though the closer to P1 that mouse gets, the larger the potential radius becomes.  Or perhaps it is the distance from the line segment between P1 and P2.

Comment: @infixed it can't be distanse beetwen P1 and P2 - when mouse loc(P2) is close to the lasted location (P1) radius looks huge. It's shows on first seconds on gif. Thats why i can't describe it shortly.

Answer (score 1):

[image: diagram]

- Tangent `A->B` implies a normal-line `Q` that passes through the (as-yet unfound) circle center `D`
- Find the midpoint `M` of chord `R` (i.e., segment `B-C`).
- A line `S` perpendicular to `R` passing through `M` also passes through `D`

So: Construct lines `Q` and `S` and find their intersection `D`.  The length of segment `B-D` is the radius of the circle.  With the radius and center `D` you should be able to calculate the arc `B->C`.

<sub>in b4 9000 hours in <s>mspaint</s>paint.net</sub>